# Manage multiple azure subscription using single email id

Tags: azure

My organization provides Managed Services to our clients. We have 5 different clients. Currently, we log into an individual subscription with client's org id.
Example:
client1's ID would be - manju@client1.com, client 2's Id would be - manju@client2.com etc.,

We are worried, if the number of client increases (which is happening), it would be difficult to manage them to keep logging in every time (different ID for different subscription) to manage their environment.

Does Azure have any mechanism such that - I can have a single ID (like a master tenant) that I can use to switch between the subscriptions? Like the one AWS has - switch role feature.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The client can add your Azure AD account as a guest to their Azure AD tenant.

They can then add rights for that user in subscriptions.

You would then be able to switch tenants from the top-right in the portal.

So they would not create a user for you, but instead invite your existing user there.

Comment: Thank you. I will look into this option.